# Trimming \n, \s, \t from javascript string

Tags: javascript, node.js, trim

I have a jQuery selector which gets the `html` within a selector, like so:

```
$('.pp-product-description .noindent').html()
```

Here's an example of the output, I've verified that it's a string:

```
    <li class="standardBulletText">600 fill power down adds warmth without weight</li>
    \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t
    <li class="standardBulletText">Matte shell with DriOff&trade; finish for water-resistant protection</li>\
    r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t
    <li class="standardBulletText">Snap-off, adjustable hood with removable faux fur trim</li>
    \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \t<li class="standardBulletText">Hidden zip/snap closure except for top and bottom snaps</li>
```

I'm trying to trim this down so that the `\r`, `\n` and `\t` characters disappear. I'm currently using `nodeJS`' [`validate` module](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) which has a special `sanitize(string).trim()` command which should trim away white space. From the docs:

```
var str = sanitize(' \t\r hello \n').trim();         //'hello'
```

This has worked for me in the past, but here it isn't. I've also tried javascript's built in `trim()` method, as well as `str.replace("\s+", "");`, none are working.

Any ideas on what I'm missing, or what I can do to get this working?

Comment: Well, the whitespace is not at the beginning nor the end so `trim` won't do anything, and the regex you tried is a string not a regex, so that won't do anything either...

Comment: @rps That's not working for me.

Comment: @Jascination Notice, that `.replace()` just returns a replaced string. You need to do `str = str.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HkJbr/....

`.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"")`

Comment: It is replacing all the occurrences not trimming from left and right side of a string. Does not work in case of trimming. Thanks.